# How to generate error on assignment to \count register if value being assigned contains decimal point?

Tags: plain-tex, registers, count

Please, if possible, plain TeX + eTeX commands only (I compile in XeLaTeX but use TeX commands).

I need parameter value to be an integer value, not a decimal. In this example, parameter is being assigned to `\count255`. But if parameter contains decimal point, the decimal of the number is being displayed. So instead of displaying the decimal, I somehow need to trigger an error (or get rid of the decimal part during or before assignment).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\def\zTest#1{%
  \count255=#1 % how to generate error on decimal point?
  \the\count255 % displays integer, but decimal has already been displayed as a side effect of assignment
}
\begin{document}
  \zTest{3.7} % would assign 3 to \count but display .7 as side effect
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the decimal part of the number passed and then test whether that decimal part is non-empty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\zTestdot#1.#2\@nil{#2}
\def\zTest#1{%
  \edef\temp{\zTestdot#1.\@nil}% Capture decimal content
  \if\relax\temp\relax
    \count255=#1 %
    \the\count255 %
  \else % Decimal content existed
    \@latex@error{Don't include decimals to \string\zTest}{}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\zTest{3.7} % would assign 3 to \count but display .7 as side effect

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume `\@nil` is from LaTeX? Where can I at least take a look at how it's defined?

Comment: @bp2017: `\@nil` in this case is just a way to delimit or identify the end of the parameter text for `\zTestdot`. It doesn't mean anything. It could have been `\relax` or something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\afterassignment`:

```latex
\def\zTest#1{\afterassignment\zTestAux\count255=#1\relax}
\def\zTestAux#1{\ifx\relax#1\else\ERROR\expandafter\zTestGobble\fi}
\def\zTestGobble#1\relax{}

\zTest{3}\the\count255\ should print 3

\zTest{\count255}\the\count255\ should print 3

\zTest{4.1}\the\count255\ should print 4 and raise error

\bye
```

Define `\ERROR` to do what you like best.